# Prevent axes from cutting off dots in matplotlib scatter plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [0, 1, 7, 2]

plt.scatter(x, y, color='red')
plt.title('number of iterations')
plt.xlim([1, 4])
plt.ylim([1, 8])
```

If one was to plot this data, the dots on the axes are partially cut off. Is there a way to prevent this (i.e. can the dots be plotted on top of the axes)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the `clip_on` attribute to `False` allows you to go beyond the axes, but by default the axes will be on top. For example, the script

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [0, 1, 7, 2]

plt.scatter(x, y, color="red", clip_on=False)
plt.title('number of iterations')
plt.xlim([1, 4])
plt.ylim([1, 8])
```

Yields the following.

[image]

Note that the axes "cut through" the dots. If you want the dots to go on top of the axes/labels, you need to change the default `zorder`. For example, the script

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [0, 1, 7, 2]

plt.scatter(x, y, color="red", clip_on=False, zorder = 10)
plt.title('number of iterations')
plt.xlim([1, 4])
plt.ylim([1, 8])
```

yields

[image]

*Note: any `zorder` value 3 or greater will work here*.

Comment: @tdy Thanks for catching that